# How to override the side-menu in bootstrap - Yii

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I've configure blackboot (i.e. bootstrap) on yii and I've been using it for the past couple of weeks to develop my website. However, at this point I'm running into a slight problem. Generally, the pages that are generated have a top menu, a side menu (on the left side that says something like "Create XXXX" "Manage XXXXX"_ and the content displayed in the center. I'd like to be able to delete the current menu and instead use that space to display my own form/field. The current code in the index view is

```
<?php
/* @var $this RecipientController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Recipients',
);
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Recipient', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Recipient', 'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/create', array('id'=>$id))),

);
?>




<h1> Recipients </h1> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 offset6">  
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href= 
            "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/processpayment', array('id'=>$id)); ?>"> Pay All </a>
        <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/create', array('id'=>$id)); ?>" >Add User</a>
    <div class ="span4"> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
</div>


<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'recipient-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'position',
        'msisdn',
        'balance',
        /* 
        * this is to implement the checklist 
        array(
            'id'=>'autoId',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '50',   
        ),
        */ 
    ),
)); ?>



<?
/* 
php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
));
*/ 
 ?>
```

In which $this->menu() defines the area that I would like to be using. In its place I would like to put this html.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('recipient/processpayment', array('id'=>$id)) ?>" method="post" >
        <tr class="primary"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;List Summary</td></tr>
        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $numpeople; ?> Recipients
        </td></tr>

        <tr ><td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Total Due: &nbsp;<?php echo $totaldue ?> rwf
        </td></tr>

        <tr> <td> 
            <?php 
                $accounts= CHtml::listData(Account::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"user_id = $user_id")),'id', 'name');
                echo CHtml::dropDownList("listF",'id', $accounts); 
            ?>
       </td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td> 
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary " type="submit">Pay Now</button>  </td> </tr> 
        </td></tr>
    </form>

  </table>

</div>
<div class="span9"></div>
</div>
```

But, whenever I try to place this small box inside of my web page - I am forced to place it inside of the main blank page in the center. How can I override this menu/html so that I can place my own form on the left side of the page?